# Extra empty plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using this code to plot the iris dataset gives me an extra empty plot:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

d = {'Species': ['setosa', 'versicolor','virginica'], 'Sepal length': [1, 2, 3], 'Sepal width': [2, 4, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


unv = df['Species'].unique()
colorv = ['r','b','g']
markerv = ['v', 'o', '>']


#Getting an extra empty plot for no reason
fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,2)
for i in range(len(unv)):
    df[df['Species'] == unv[i]].plot(x="Sepal length", y="Sepal width", kind="scatter",ax=ax[0],label=unv[i],color=colorv[i], marker = markerv[i])

plt.show()
```

Any suggestions why I receive this extra plot and how I can remove it?
[image]

Comment: `fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,2)` is creating 2 axes (plots). If `unv` has only one element, then you get only one iteration and one plot. Try to print `len(unv)`. If this is not it, check if one of the elements is not empty. A way to avoid the first issue is to do: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(unv))`.

Comment: Hmm..does not quite work. The length of unv is 3, and thus I get 3 plots

Comment: You need to understand that we can't reproduce your example. So you have 3 elements in `unv`, as I could have guess with the use of 3 colors and markers. Thus why are you creating only 2 axes? Did you check the data you are trying to plot (`iris[iris['Species'] == unv[i]]`)?

Comment: why do you have subplots(1,2)? your code looks like you want to plot everything on the same axes

Comment: I want only 1 plot, but if I go for fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,1) I get an error.
And yes, data iris[iris['Species'] == unv[i]]) is alright

Comment: The main problem of this difficult communication is, as pointed out by @Mathieu, the lack of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 2 subplots because you are requesting two subplots by calling `plt.subplots(1,2)`, which creates 1*2 subplots on 1 line and 2 columns.

The answer to your question is therefore to call `plt.subplots(1,1)`.
In the comments, you say you have tried but you get an error. This is expected. [The documentation states](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) (emphasis mine):

> Returns:
>
> fig : matplotlib.figure.Figure object
>
> ax : **Axes object or array of
>   Axes objects.**
>
> ax can be either **a single matplotlib.axes.Axes object or an array of Axes
>   objects** if more than one subplot was created. The dimensions
>   of the resulting array can be controlled with the squeeze keyword, see
>   above.

if `subplots()` returns only one axes, then it returns that Axes object instead of a list, therefore you should modify your call to:

```
df[df['Species'] == unv[i]].plot( (...) ,ax=ax, (...) )
```